# What did I do wrong in my interview for a US tourist visa? What can I do to avoid refusal in the future?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I went to the US embassy in New Delhi with my wife for a B2 visa interview. This is how the interview went:

> **Interviewer**: Why are you going to USA?
>
> **Me**: We are going for tourism.
>
> **Interviewer**: Where are you going?
>
> **Me**: We are going to New York, Washington, Niagara Falls.
>
> **Interviewer**: What do you do?
>
> **Me**: I am doing my XXXXX business.
>
> **Interviewer**: (*to my wife*) What do you do, madam?
>
> **My wife**: I help my husband in his business and take care of my family.
>
> **Interviewer**: Do you have anyone in USA?
>
> **Me**: Yes, I have my friend but we are going through a tour package.
>
> **Interviewer**: So your friend is not going to accompany you?
>
> **Me**: (*I was quiet. I didn't said anything*)
>
> **Interviewer**: Why did you go to the United Kingdom?
>
> **Me**: I went there for tourism.
>
> Interviewer handed me a [214(B) refusal slip](http://iran.usembassy.gov/visas/214b-refusal.html) and said "**our rules
>   are strict, we can't issue you a visa**".

I am doing my business here in Punjab, India and my wife is a sales manager in my company. We have a good income. We have good savings and land purchased here. We have all the proof of income, savings and land.

I would like to reapply for a B2 visa again. What should I do to improve my chances?

Comment: Haven't you already asked this before? I can't find it off-hand, but I'm sure I've read this question a few days ago.

Comment: [Read this very carefully.](http://newdelhi.usembassy.gov/consular/refused-or-pending-visa/214b-refusal.html)

Comment: @MarkMayo I remember it too; must have been deleted.

Comment: Why didn't you answer the question about whether your friend was accompanying you on the tour?

Comment: Yes I asked the same thing.i made the new post coz everyone said that they dont understand what I am looking for . Now I want to reapply for B2 visa with my wife .please help me how I can present my self how I can tell them I have strong ties and please help me to fill ds-160 form and how I have to amswer them to explain what I am . Yes Iade a mistake about my friend accompany .I have to tell them I ill meet my friend end of my trip .thanks for ir time thanks alot for ur help

Comment: @lally.ab If you register an account, you can then edit previous questions, which would be better than asking the same question again.

Comment: I've heavily edit the question to make it nice and clear. I hope lally.ab doesn't mind :)

Answer (score 12):

There could be countless other things you haven't mentioned, but if you apply again, don't stay silent when answering a question!  They asked about whether or not your friend is accompanying you.  You stayed silent. That's a BIG red flag - anyone refusing to answer a question implicitly indicates they have something to hide.

They want to be sure you're a genuine, open tourist with no ulterior motives. Appearing to hide information does not convince them of this.